# How to draw animation frames with CustomPainter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a CustomPainter that can paint all sorts of visuals based on a physical model input parameters.

How can I make a 1 second animation that draws the needed frames between two different end points, essentially calling my CustomPainter to paint intermediate values between the two end points whenever a new frame can be drawn?

```
Container(
            width: 800,
            height: 500,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: MyPainter(
                context,
                inputVal: myProvider
              ),
            ))
```

Basically I want to make a function that runs a one second long sequence where values in myProvider change incrementally from start values to end values, and the CustomPaint redraws the visuals based on current values whenever a new frame is drawn. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check out tween animation. I think it should help you.

Comment: Thank you! TweenAnimationBuilder did the trick: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html